# lenovo thinkpad edge 11. "burned" a little bit?

Tags: laptop

I give my lenovo thinkpad edge 11 to my friend and he returned it to my a little bit "burned"

[image: laptop]

[image]
It seems laptop was so hot that he started to "burn". Note "circle" and disappeared numbers. What is that? Is it safe to keep using this laptop? I'm afraid that battery might be broken. However laptop still working.

Comment: Is it under warranty?

Comment: no it is not under warranty.

Comment: Is this an OEM battery?

Comment: this is standart battery, came with laptop. i will post better quality picture soon.

Comment: That second photo looks like it might actually have been some kind of liquid damage (though it could be a heat mark too.  Hard to tell without seeing it in person)

Comment: @voretaq7 yes but surface is also damaged...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's under warranty, time to give Lenovo a call.  Otherwise, looks to me like you need to stop using that battery.  If you want to double check, I'd turn on the laptop with the battery out and observe it to make sure it's running normally.

Comment: how this stuff is happened? I just wonder if I should blame my friend or Lenovo :)

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture, but it looks to me like the battery malfunctioned and overheated to the point of melting portions of the case near it. As Hubert pointed out, it's entirely possible that your friend placed it on something hot, but barring that, it looks like a malfunctioned battery to me.

Comment: @javapowered absolutely stop using this battery ***immediately*** -- even with obstructed cooling your laptop should not overheat to a degree that can cause this sort of damage (the built-in thermal protection should have shut it down well before that point). You should also contact Lenovo with your system and battery serial numbers to report this incident.  Continuing to use the affected battery may pose a [serious fire hazard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG_UuPmLO1c) -- Lithium batteries are quite dangerous when they malfunction.

Comment: @voretaq7 i don't know. note that not only battery is affected but also part near it. I have "circle" affected. probably laptop was left on some hot surface....

Comment: @javapowered That label could very easily have been damaged by excessive heat from the battery. If you are concerned about other system damage you should follow SteveG's advice in the answer re: performing a function test with the battery removed, however the chances of something else in your laptop causing a fire/explosion are *substantially* lower than the risk with a malfunctioning battery, which is what appears to be happening here.

Comment: @javapowered If you suspect the laptop was left on a hot surface that does not negate the battery issue - any surface hot enough to melt the plastic casing is hot enough to compromise the safety/integrity of the battery pack -- I would be extremely wary of using a battery in that condition even if the cause of the damage is an external factor. (Whether your friend tried to cook and eat your laptop or not is a personal matter between the two of you. I'm only concerned about the technical and safety issues here - I don't want to read about your house burning down tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unless he placed the laptop on something hot, the only way for something like this to happen is a malfunctioning cell in the battery. No laptop battery should overheat to this degree just by restricting cooling by placing the laptop on a pillow, blanket or something similar.

Comment: why label is disappear? why I have something like "oil circle"?

Answer (score 1):

Stop using the battery and remove it, defective Lion batteries can explode and cause a fire.

Store it somewhere safe where it cannot burn a structure down.

[Some Lenovo batteries were recalled](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=BATT-LENOVO)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is why I suggested contacting Lenovo with the battery serial number in [a previous comment](http://superuser.com/questions/470413/lenovo-thinkpad-edge-11-burned-a-little-bit#comment554238_470414) - LiIon batteries do *Bad Things* when they malfunction.